# Emacs - ccls : no member named "filesystem" in namespace "std"

Tags: c++, emacs, c++17, archlinux, flycheck

Archlinux user using Emacs as a C++ IDE with the following setup : company / flycheck / lsp-ui / ccls

I'm trying to use `filesystem` library from c++17 for personal use but I can't get rid of this error in Emacs

`ccls : no member named 'filesystem' in namespace 'std'`

A quick sample of my problem

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   std::filesystem::path filePath("./sample.cpp");
   std::cout << filePath.filename() < std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Compilation and runtime are totally fine using this command :

`clang++ -std=c++17 sample.cpp`

Output : `"sample.cpp"`

But the "error" is still present inside Emacs which is kind of annoying. I tried to add `.ccls` file with the following content but that doesn't solve the problem.

```
clang++
%cpp -std=c++17        ; Also tried with gnu++17
```

Here a screenshot of the problem. Error with `cout` and `filePath` are consequences of the first one I guess because everything is good in general

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6OkG.png)

Does anybody know how to solve the problem ?

Comment: For me, your `.ccls` file works. If you check out the buffer `*ccls::stderr*`, do you see a line like `22:14:20 ccls              project.cc:284 I use /home/geza/st/.ccls: clang++ %cpp -std=c++17`? Btw., you can try the `compile_commands.json` way, it is easy to use, if you use `bear` to generate it.

Comment: It seems I have no ouput in *ccls::stderr* buffer.
The only information I found is this log before the error come
`clang failed with error 1: /usr/bin/clang -fsyntax-only -Xclang -code-completion-macros -x c++ -Xclang -code-completion-at=-:8:6 -`

I tried to generate `compile_commands.json` file with `bear` and the `makefile` i'm using but it does solve the problem.

Comment: *It does not solve the problem with compile_commands.json file. My bad

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: Try this is your `terminal`.  `$ ccls -index=$PWD` in the top level project path where `.ccls` exists. and as @geza wrote, you should read `... I use */.ccls ...`. I think your project setup isn't correct, so .ccls is in the wrong place or you selected another project path.

Comment: invoke `(lsp-describe-session)` to see that every thing is OK.

Comment: we really do need an update on this one.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue to the one you're facing, using nvim + Ale + LanguageClient-neovim. I managed to compile my code successfully using clang++ with the -std=c++20 flag. However, I couldn't get rid of the error message in nvim indicating that it couldn't find the imported member. I even built my .ccls file, but it didn't resolve the problem.

Later, I realized that while I had configured LanguageClient, I had overlooked configuring my linter (Ale). So, it might be worth checking if your linter is also set up to use c++20. Hopefully, this suggestion proves helpful to you!